# Android: ContactsContract query, need more advanced selection string

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contentprovider

i'm trying to query the `ContactContract` ContentProvider and obtain the data that the following algorithm would obtain:

```
given a phone number (input), return record...:
if(recordNumber has 7 digits) {
    if('%recordNumber' LIKE 'inputNumber') {
        return recordDisplayName;
    }
} else if(recordNumber has 10 digits) {
    if('recordNumber' LIKE '%inputNumber') {
        return recordDisplayName;
    }
} else if(recordNumber == inputNumber) {
    return recordDisplayName;
}
```

this works in the query call:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" LIKE ?"
```

but i need something more like this:

```
"('%" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"' LIKE '?' AND LENGTH("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+")=7) OR ('" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"' LIKE '%?' AND LENGTH("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+")=10)"
```

but i get runtime errors everytime i use a query with a single quote.  for instance, changing:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" LIKE ?"
```

to:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" LIKE '?'"
```

causes a runtime error "bind or column index out of range...".  so this has to be some syntax error... right?  what's the proper syntax for `ContentProvider` queries and/or how can i get the result set i'm after from `ContactsContract`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

queries to ContentProviders are a little different, and unforgiving on the formatting.  for ContentProviders, if you want to use '%' as a wildcard character, the '%' must be concatenated to the argument in the WHERE clause, rather than as a part of the clause itself.

correct:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
    null, 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" LIKE ?",
    new String[] { "%"+number },
    null);
```

incorrect:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
    null, 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" LIKE %?", 
    new String[] { number }, 
    null);
```

the above "incorrect" statement is actually completely legal for SQLite queries, just not for ContentProvider queries.

in addition, single quotes are a syntax error in a ContentProvider query's WHERE clause (or concatenated to the args in said clause).

final code:

```
if(number.length()==7) {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+" LIKE ?",
        //"('%" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"' LIKE '?' AND LENGTH("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+")=7) OR ('" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"' LIKE '%?' AND LENGTH("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+")=10)",
        new String[] { "%"+number },
        null);
} else if(number.length()==10) {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
        "("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"=? AND LENGTH("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+")=7) OR ("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"=? AND LENGTH("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+")=10)",
        new String[] { number.substring(3), number },
        null);
} else {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"=?",
        new String[] { number },
        null);
}
```

this code will retrieve matching display names for phone numbers that match the number in question.
- if the number is a 7 digit number, we retrieve any records who's phone numbers last 7 digits (dashes and special characters stripped, except "*" and "#" since they are valid phone characters) match the 7 digits of the number in question.
- if the number is a 10 digit number, it returns any records that either contain 7 digits and match the last 7 characters, or contain an exact match in the case that the record has 10 digits.
- if the number in question has neither 7 nor 10 digits, an exact match is necessary.

Comment: I had a problem with this (kind of) query, until I noticed the usage of Data.CONTENT_URI, and not CONTENT_FILTER_URI. I just realized my semantic misunderstanding. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Use  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER instead of  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER